# Convert JsonObject array to integer

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am getting the following response from my server:

```
{"SubjectName":["Irish","Maths","English","Science","Religion","Geography"],
"SubjectID":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

What I need to do is try separate the response into two separate arrays SubjectName and SubjectID.

Here is what I have:

```
 try {
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SubjectName");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SubjectName = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            try {
                SubjectName[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SUBJECTID");
            Log.v("Worked", "SubjectID is in ");

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.v("failed","Not able to retrieve data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SubjectID = new int[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {

            try {
                SubjectID[i] = jsonArray.getInt(i);
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }
```

The String seems to convert no problem and I can get the SubjectName but the SubjectID part seems to  fail and I have no idea why. I've checked and I can't seem to find anywhere that shows me how to parse an int from the jsonaray.

Comment: FYI: you cannot `convert array into integer`.it's just container with no numeric value. You can however try with its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong node name.

Replace

```
jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SUBJECTID");
```

with

```
jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SubjectID");
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot thanks I was searching for an hour

Comment: @ecribs Don't worry about it. It happens to everyone. Please don't forget to accept it if works for you.